# Calculating dates from datepicker in computed vue function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out the best way to generate fields based on date count, otherwise show a default.

I have the default of 11 days working perfectly, but I want to take the difference between dates if the two datepickers are set. So if no dates are set, there would be 11 dates printed, but if someone picked today and 3 days from now, there would be 4 days printed

I think because the `dates()` function is in the computed portion it's not picking up the datepicker values maybe? It works with hardcoded numbers but not the datepickers

How can I alter this so that if the datepickers are set, I can return an array of the selected dates?

```js
var vm = 
new Vue({
  data: {
    startDateModel: '',
    endDateModel: '',
    pendingStartDate:'',
    pendingEndDate:''
  },
  methods: {
    
    getStartDate(event){
      this.pendingStartDate = {"event_target":event.target};
    },
    getEndingDate(event){
      this.pendingEndDate = {"event_target":event.target};
    },
  },
  computed: {
   
    dates() {
     if(this.pendingStartDate !== '' && this.pendingEndDate !== ''){
        var diff_in_days = Math.abs(new Date(this.pendingEndDate.event_target.value) - new Date(this.pendingStartDate.event_target.value));
        var days = Math.ceil(diff_in_days / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var startDate = new Date(this.pendingStartDate.event_target.value);

        return Array.from(Array(11), (_, i) => new Date(Date.startDate() + i * 86400000).toISOString().slice(0,days))
      }else{
        return Array.from(Array(11), (_, i) => new Date(Date.now() + i * 86400000).toISOString().slice(0,10))
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="position:relative !important;">
      <input
         v-on:blur="getStartDate($event)" 
         v-model="startDateModel"
         type="text"
         data-uk-datepicker="{minDate:'{{date_format(new DateTime('tomorrow'),'Y-m-d')}}', format:'YYYY-MM-DD'}"
      >
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative !important;">
      <input 
         v-on:blur="getEndingDate($event)" 
         v-model="endDateModel"
         type="text"
         data-uk-datepicker="{minDate:'{{date_format(new DateTime('tomorrow'),'Y-m-d')}}', format:'YYYY-MM-DD'}"
      >
    </div>
    

<th v-for="date in dates" :key="date">@{{ date }}</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your use of the "data-uk-datepicker" attribute it seems that you're using a custom datepicker component ([UiKit](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/datepicker.html)?), and that the way you're handling events and model bindings is built around the workings of that component.

The behavior you want to achieve can be abstracted into simpler logic, and from then you'll have an easier time attaching it to components or handling presentation.

Here's how you could code your component using native HTML fields and plain JS dates:

```
var vm = 
new Vue({
  data: function() {
    return {
      startDate: '',
      endDate: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {

    // List all dates between startDate and endDate, as ISO formatted strings:
    dates() {
      var objStartDate, objEndDate

      if (!this.startDate || !this.endDate) {
        // Default values: 11 days starting today
        objStartDate = new Date()
        objEndDate = new Date()
        objEndDate.setDate(objEndDate.getDate() + 10)
      } else {
        objStartDate = new Date(this.startDate)
        objEndDate = new Date(this.endDate)
      }

      // Iterate through the date range
      var retval = []
      for (var d = objStartDate; d <= objEndDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        retval.push(d.toISOString().slice(0, 10))
      }
      return retval
    },
  },
});
```

```
  <div>
    <input
      v-model="startDate"
      type="date"
    >

    <input
      v-model="endDate"
      type="date"
    >

    <p>Dates:</p>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="date in dates"
        :key="date"
      >
        @{{ date }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```